# Scraping using Beautiful Soup leads to error only in a particular section (NullType object encountered)

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of injuries of a particular team (liverpool in this case) from the following website

http://www.physioroom.com/news/english_premier_league/epl_injury_table.php

It works fine with certain teams(Swansea), but exits with the following errors for some (Liverpool, Everyon)

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


url = "http://www.physioroom.com/news/english_premier_league/epl_injury_table.php"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
#lp = soup.find(alt="Liverpool away shirt").parent.parent.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling
lp = soup.find(alt="Swansea City away shirt").parent.parent.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling
player_info = ""
player_list = []

while True:
    if(lp.has_attr('id')):
            break
    else:
            tdlist = lp.find_all('td')#     player_info = tdlist[0].string+"\t"+tdlist[1].string+"\t"+tdlist[3].string
            #print(tdlist[0].find('a').string.strip() + "\t" + tdlist[1].string.strip() + "\t" + tdlist[3].string.strip())
            print(tdlist[0].string + "\t" + tdlist[1].string + "\t" + tdlist[3].string)
            lp=lp.findNext('tr')
```

Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: I've fixed it. Never mind. Some of the tags contained <a> and had to be treated in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "http://www.physioroom.com/news/english_premier_league/epl_injury_table.php"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id='epl-table')
for tr in table('tr', id=None):
    print(tr.get_text('\t', strip=True))
```

out:

```
PLAYER  CONDITION   LATEST NEWS EXPECTED RETURN AVAILABLE?
D Meyler    Knock   No Return Date  Slight Doubt
S Maloney   Ear Infection   No Return Date  Slight Doubt
M Henriksen Shoulder Separation April 1, 2017   Major Doubt
A McGregor  Fitness No Return Date  Major Doubt
W Keane ACL Knee Injury No Return Date
M Odubajo   Patella Fracture    May 1, 2017
G Luer  Knee Injury February 1, 2017
```

[get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:

You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together

You can tell Beautiful Soup to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each bit of text

Comment: Thank you!! This seems so much simpler than my long way around. I don't have any reputation to mark you as answer yet.

Comment: @wolfcubman http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work